# Why is my html code only partly colored in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

As you can see in the screenshot my code is only partly colored. If I go to a tag and hit enter after it it gets colored as well. Cutting and pasting does not help. As you can see in the bottom right corner the language is set to HTML. So what's the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity= "sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <!-- Script -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
I have noticed that pasting the following code in the header is causing trouble. Any tags added before will not be colored. Also if I cut and paste the code after adding the bit below, everything is uncolored.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity= "sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

If you hit enter manually then atom colors that?
Try changing line endings to UNIX.

(cmd-shift-p on macOS), type Convert and then use Convert to LF and: Convert to CRLF commands from there.

Comment: ctrl+shift+l, and select auto-detect option.

Comment: this did not work and it would have been odd if it did, since the language was set to HTML already.